# Graphic Python in Rstudio

Tags: python, rstudio

How do I stop accumulating legends of python graphics generated in Rstudio? See in the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNAtt.png), is accumulated the legend of the graphics that I plotted earlier.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt

def countplot(v1):
    sns.countplot(data=df,x=v1,palette="Set2",hue=v1,dodge=False)

countplot("Situacao")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does your data look like? It seems like your legend labels aren't recognized correctly.

Comment: @Quastiat I believe the problem is not the data, when I do the graph for the first time it's ok, but in the next graphics  begins to accumulate, I believe it's something in Rstudio itself that is causing this

Comment: okay so did you try to run the same code in an different IDE, maybe Spyder or jupyternotebook and check if the error disappears?

Comment: in Spyder it's ok